# Why am I getting 'Undefined Control Space' error?

Tags: errors

I've come across some issues whilst compiling. I am using TeXShop and everything was working just fine and then suddenly I got this block of code:

[image]

Not sure what's wrong with it... :'(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're compiling with `pdftex` rather than `pdflatex`, somehow you've made Texshop switch from one to the other.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out Torbjorn - and thanks for the welcome :)